# Got HTTP Status 405 in case of logout from Grails application with Spring Security Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, logout

I'm adding Spring Security plugin(2.0 RC3) to my Grails app(2.4.4). However, once clicking 'Logout' link i see the web page with `HTTP Status 405`.

How this could be fixed?

Answer (score 18):

The reason of that could be found by analysis of LogoutController code

```
class LogoutController {

    def index() {

        if (!request.post && SpringSecurityUtils.getSecurityConfig().logout.postOnly) {
            response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED // 405
            return
        }

        // TODO put any pre-logout code here
        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl 
    }
}
```

So there are two fixes available:

1) Change 'Logout' link to send POST request.

```
<form name="logout" method="POST" action="${createLink(controller:'logout') }"> 
<input type="submit" value="logout"></form>
```

2) Or just add following line to *Config.groovy*

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
```